# random value in java depending on field type

Tags: java, reflection, random

Is there any way to get random value depending on field type?? The exact scenario is I used reflection to get declared fields of a class. I want to set fake data to the fields I got.

```
Field fieldset[] = cls.getDeclaredFields();
```

for a field fld of fieldlist I can get type using `fld.getType()`
but I have to set random value depending on type during runtime

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

`random.nextInt()` gives me an integer...but all I want is if there is anymetod or way like `rand(fldtype)` which should give me a random value of field type

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke the method on the random class using reflexion, and have a Map that maps types to functions for the random class. This would allow you to do only one comparison, and add/remove types with less maintenance.

However, you would have difficulty casting the return type in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random number between 0 to (no of fields) -1 and get the field you need.

Code is something like this.

```
Field fieldset[] = cls.getDeclaredFields();
int noOfFiledsLessOne=fieldset.length-1;

Random rand=new Random()

Integer i=rand.float()*noOfFiledsLessOne;

Field randField=fieldset[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this roughly what you need? `Class<?>` is the return type of `Field.getType()`

```
private static final List<Class<?>> seeds = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();

public static int rand(Class<?> clazz) {
  int seed = seeds.indexOf(clazz);
  if(seed == -1) {
    seeds.add(clazz);
    seed = seeds.size() - 1;
  }

  Random random = new Random(seed);
  return random.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: no actually....my code should be able to give randon string or random int or random long or rand float....